# HP laptop doesn't charge when it is turned on

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

I have an HP Pavillion laptop since 2009 February and it recently started to not get batteries charged when it is turned on. What could be the problem? Is it a battery problem or another? Has anyone had such experience yet?

P.S. The light next to the cable on the laptop is on, and when I plug-out then re-plug-in the cable it starts to charge 3-4 seconds and stops.

Comment: Does the battery actually deplete and does that cause the laptop to shutdown?

Comment: Yes exactly, BTW I didn't know that I can remove the battery and power on the laptop. Now it works without battery fine. I am getting convinced that the reson was battery. But it is strange that when the battery is 0 it shutes down insted of using power supply.

Comment: Could also be the power circuit that doesn't properly work anymore...

Comment: No, I don't think so because power enters into the laptop as the light is on next to the place AC power adapter plugs in.

Comment: The power circuit charges your battery, it is broken because it doesn't charge when the laptop is on.

Comment: @Moab Thanks for asking that, somehow it didn't make sense. Should be clear now.

Comment: Seems it is beacause of some edits or may be my mistake, but now it is ok. Just it chages when laptop is turen off and doesn't charge when it is one (or may be it charges but slower then it uses the charge :D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with my laptop was power supply. It was shorted which in its turn damaged the motherboard part with is resposible on signaling to power supply to charge it.